# How to create a circle with a text in the middle and across the edges in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

If possible I would like to create this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am3Jz.png) in CSS. So far I have not been able to do anything even close to those edges with text. Is it even possible and if so how should I approach it?

Comment: Are you asking how to transform a div into a circle?

Answer (score 0):

To turn your div into a circle you can apply the following property: `border-radius: 100%` Now if you are asking about the curved text, here is an article that might be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/